# How to call binance api class in php construtor?

Tags: php

I am trying to call binance api class in construct method in my controller so that I can access that api class instance throught entire controller. Problem lies that I need to pass $key and $secret variables to binance class in order to get that object, but I can not do that in construct method. I tried making config.ini file and calling it with parse_ini_file but that returned error that I can not use that function inside class. Here is my code. Any help is appreciated or if someone has other idea on how to make this work.

controller

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

class BinanceController 
{
    private $api;
    private $key = 'some long string 1';
    private $secret = 'some long string 2';

    $api = new Binance\API($key,$secret); // SOMEHOW I NEED LIKE THIS!!!

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->api = new Binance\API($this->key,$this->secret);
    }

    public function getAllBinancePairs()
    {
        $exchangeInfo = $this->api->exchangeInfo(); // HERE IS SOURCE OF ERROR!!!

        $results = [];

        foreach($exchangeInfo['symbols'] as $info) {
            $results[] = $info['symbol']; 
     
        }

        json_response($results);
    }
}
```

index.php

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$router = new AltoRouter();

$router->map( 'GET', '/fbinance', function() {
    require __DIR__ . '/fbinance.php';
});


$router->map('GET','/get-all-binance-pairs', array('c' => 'BinanceController', 'a' => 'getAllBinancePairs'));

$match = $router->match();

if(!isset($match['target']['c']))
{
    header( $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 404 Server Error', true, 404);
}


switch($match['target']['c']) {
    case "BinanceController": 
        include 'controllers/BinanceController.php';
        if( $match && is_callable("BinanceController::" . $match['target']['a']) ) {
            call_user_func_array("BinanceController::" . $match['target']['a'], $match['params'] ); 
        } else {
            // no route was matched
            header( $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 404 Server Error', true, 404);
            exit;
        }
        break;
    default:
        header( $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 404 Server Error', true, 404);
        break;
}
```

Comment: Please share more details - how do you call that controller itself?

Answer (score 2):

If the arguments to the constructor for that API are not public, you can only instantiate it within the constructor of `BinanceController` like:

```php
class BinanceController 
{
    private $api;
    private $key = 'some long string 1';
    private $secret = 'some long string 2';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->api = new Binance\API($this->key,$this->secret);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, but now when I try something like this $exchangeInfo = $this->api->exchangeInfo(); in another function I get error ' Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in controller'

Comment: Please share more details. Where is this "other function"? Within that class?

Comment: I updated the question. Now you have second function where I call $this->api and get error, and I added index.php which is entry file for routes

Comment: Sounds like you are calling `getAllBinancePairs` as a static function from your router. That's something that is obviously not possible if you want to access `$this` within that method. Either properly instantiate the controller class (such that you can use everything in a object-based context), or don't use a constructor after all

Comment: Can you give me an example on how this would work if I don't use constructor, or example on how to properly instantiate controller class, either works?